Recurrence relation $a_{n+1} = a_n - \sqrt{a_n}$.
I'm aware it might be hard to solve but is there a way to approximate a solution to such a recurrence relation? I'm thinking of the case where $a(0)$ is some positive integer.

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1545363/42969 – found with Approach0

Hello and welcome to Math.SE. Please provide more informations like where does equation come from, what's your motivation, what did you try to solve it / what are your thoughts behind this equation, ... Your question is of the form "This is my problem. Please solve it." and that does not meet this sites standards.

Look at $$\sqrt{a_{n+1}}-\sqrt{a_n}=\frac{(a_n-\sqrt{a_n})-a_n}{\sqrt{a_n-\sqrt{a_n}}+\sqrt{a_n}}\asymp -\frac12$$ for large $a_n\gg\sqrt{a_n}$. Continue with telescoping. Employing the binomial series of the square root can lead to more exact approximations.
